# Extract numeric and text parts of a string, in varying formats

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to put together a RegEx to split a variety of possible user inputs, and while I've managed to succeed with some cases, I've not managed to cover every case that I'd like to.

**Possible inputs, and expected outputs**

```
"1 day" > [1,"day"]
"1day" > [1,"day"]
"10,000 days" > [10000,"days"]
```

Is it possible to split the numeric and text parts from the string without necessarily having a space, and to also remove the commas etc from the string at the same time?

[This is what I've got at the moment](http://regexr.com/3ged3)

```
[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+
```

Which seems to split the numeric and text portions nicely, but is tripped up by commas. (Actually, as I write this, I'm thinking I could use the last part of the results array as the text part, and concatenate all the other parts as the numeric part?)

Comment: Show us what you got so far

Comment: Haha! Fair enough, this is by far the laziest looking question I've ever posted on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var test = [
    '1 day',
    '1day',
    '10,000 days',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  a = a.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g, '$1$2'); // remove the commas
  return a.match(/^(\d+)\s*(.+)$/);    // split in two parts
}));
```

Comment: Toto, je t'aime! Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression works, apart from removing the comma from the matched number string:

```
([0-9,]+]) *(.*)
```

You cannot "ignore" a character in a returned regular expression match string, so you will just have to remove the comma from the returned regex match afterwards.

Comment: Thanks CC, I hadn't entirely grasped that about Regex, so it's good to know for future reference (and explains why Toto did it in two steps in his answer).